# Implement hook_node_access based on field value

Tags: users

I need to implement hook_node_access based on field value, which I can get only via $form variable. At the moment I cannot do this because I only have variables ($node, $op, $account) available in hook_node_access. Could you please help me to find the way how to implement something like:

if ($form['...']['...'] == 'TRUE') {return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the node form to access its fields to check for conditional access. Use the field data in your node object.

```
if($node->my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == 'TESTED_VALUE') {
  return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is not exacltly the node field - this is a checkbox in comment (module Support Ticketing System) which states who is subscribed for email notification. I can see these checkboxes only via dsm($form).

Comment: I would look at the code for the support module then. Find out how it loads/stores data for that comment (maybe one of the support_ tables?) and loads it for a specific node id. Once you have that, you can load it inside your hook_node_access invocation and perform your access check.

Comment: Tanks a lot. I'll check as well.

Comment: Hi Shawn, I've checked the database and unfortunatelly didn't find records related to these checkboxes. Do I have any other options to complete the task?

Comment: You could try searching the support module codebase for "checkbox". That should give you some hints where the form builder for the checkbox is at. With the form builder code you can find out how the data stored/retrieved.